While my nextJS cannot run loop (for,while)
i set my while loop and console.log it but the console just return only 1 not,
while loop just return 1 and i cannot custom my pagination component by my logic

import React from 'react'
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from 'lucide-react'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { toltalPageGlobal } from '@/data/data';
import Link from 'next/link';

const handleItem = (totalPage: number, curPage: number, slugPath: string) => {
  const items = [];
  let count = 1;
  while (count < totalPage + 1) {
    console.log(count)
    items.push(
      <Link
        key={count}
        href={`/${slugPath}/get?size=10&page=${curPage - 1}`}
        aria-current="page"
        className={`${count === curPage ? 'bg-indigo-600' : ''}relative z-10 inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white focus:z-20 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600`}
      >
        {curPage}
      </Link>)
    if (count > curPage - 2 || count < curPage + 2) {
      <span key={`ellipsis-${count}`} className="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:outline-offset-0">
        ...
      </span>
      count=(count < curPage-2) ? curPage-2 : totalPage-1
    }
    count++;
  }
 return items; 
};
export default function PaginationComponent() {

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const curPage = Number(searchParams.get('page')) + 1;
  const pathName = usePathname()
  const slugPath = pathName.substring(0, pathName.indexOf('/', 1)); //slug/get?size=10&page=cur&
  const totalPage = toltalPageGlobal.value;
  // login pagination

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between border-t w-full border-gray-200 bg-white px-4 py-3 sm:px-6">

      <div className=" sm:flex sm:flex-1 sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
        <div>
          <p className="text-sm text-gray-700">
            Showing <span className="font-medium">{curPage}</span> to <span className="font-medium">{totalPage}</span> of{' '}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <nav className="isolate inline-flex -space-x-px rounded-md shadow-sm" aria-label="Pagination">
            <Link
              href={`/${slugPath}/get?size=10&page=${curPage - 1}`}
              className={`${curPage === 1 ? 'hidden' : ''} relative inline-flex items-center rounded-r-md px-2 py-2 text-gray-400 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-20 focus:outline-offset-0`}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
              <ChevronLeft className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
            {handleItem(totalPage, curPage, slugPath)}
            <Link
              href={`/${slugPath}/get?size=10&page=${curPage + 1}`}
              className={`${curPage === totalPage} relative inline-flex items-center rounded-r-md px-2 py-2 text-gray-400 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-20 focus:outline-offset-0`}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">NEXT</span>
              <ChevronRight className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


I tried just leaving the while alone and it still only returns 1 number and doesn't end
while(count<5){
  console.log(count)
  count++;
}

while and for loop doesn't run in nextjs and typescript
